# e.stopPropagation() and .slideToggle() at war inside click events

Tags: javascript, jquery, click, slidetoggle, stoppropagation

I've got a child `close` button inside its parent, a notification box. When the parent is clicked, the notification box expands, with the notification's description and the child button becoming visible inside it.

The button, when clicked, should unexpand the notification and hide both itself and the description.

Because the button has a click event inside its parent click event, both were being called. I turned to `event.stopPropagation()` to have the parent notification stop re-expanding after I clicked. While this stopped the notification from expanding on a close button click, it presented a new problem that I don't understand.

In my test, I have two notifications set up, both unexpanded. When I click on a notification, it expands and shows the description and close button. When I click the close button, the notification unexpands and the button and description are hidden. *But, I found that the description and close button were appearing for the other notification!*

Code:

```
    var $NotificationContainer = $("#NotificationContainer");
    $NotificationContainer.append('<div class="Notification" title="'+title+'"></div>');

    var $thisNotification = $NotificationContainer.children('.Notification[title='+title+']');
    $thisNotification.append('<div class="NotificationTitle">'+title+'</div>');
    $thisNotification.append('<div class="NotificationDescription">'+description+'</div>');
    $(".NotificationDescription").hide();

    // Button used to close an expanded notification
    $thisNotification.append("<div class='NotificationCloseButton'></div>");
    $('.NotificationCloseButton').hide();

    // When the parent notification box is clicked
    $thisNotification.click(function(event)
    {
        $thisNotification.animate({height:250}, 1000);
        $thisNotification.find('.NotificationDescription').slideToggle('fast');
        $thisNotification.find('.NotificationCloseButton').slideToggle('fast');
    });

    // When the child close button is clicked
    $(".NotificationCloseButton").click(function(event)
    {
        event.stopPropagation();
        $thisNotification.animate({height:50}, 1000);
        $thisNotification.find('.NotificationDescription').slideToggle('fast');
        $thisNotification.find('.NotificationCloseButton').slideToggle('fast');
    });
```

I don't know how `$thisNotification.find('element')` is not catching the right notification.

Comment: Can you post the HTML structure of a notification?

Comment: I don't actually have a specific HTML file/code for any part of this, but I can post the CSS if you like?

Answer (score 1):

Does it work if you change the event handling to

```
// When the parent notification box is clicked
    $thisNotification.click(function(event)
    {
        var self = $(this);
        self.animate({height:250}, 1000);
        self.find('.NotificationDescription').slideToggle('fast');
        self.find('.NotificationCloseButton').slideToggle('fast');
    });

    // When the child close button is clicked
    $(".NotificationCloseButton").click(function(event)
    {
        var self = $(this);
        event.stopPropagation();
        self.animate({height:50}, 1000);
        self.find('.NotificationDescription').slideToggle('fast');
        self.find('.NotificationCloseButton').slideToggle('fast');
    });
```

used `this` to identify the `clicked` element, instead of relying on the variable that was defined when you created the element (*avoids cases in loops where the all elements reference the last value assigned to the variable..*)

---

Additionally, since you are appending to the `#NotificationContainer` you can just select the last item instead of searching for identical titles..

```
var $thisNotification = $NotificationContainer.children().last();
```

removed the selector completely since you have just appended the last element..

Comment: Yes, had tried using `$(this).find...` before, but it does not work. In particular with your example, it expands the close button to 50 but does nothing else (visibly).